# php echo parse syntax error

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

I am trying to put a language for all website. I have tried all ways around it, but nothing works - still getting the same or new error about syntax error. I am newbie and learning. Help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
page::title('<?php echo $lang['PROFILE_EDIT_PROFILE'];?>'); ?>
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'PROFILE_EDIT_PROFILE' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in
```

Comment: Try: `page::title($lang['PROFILE_EDIT_PROFILE']);`

Comment: Lawrence Cherone - you are God! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though you don't need to `echo` here and could just use the variable directly:

```
<?php
page::title($lang['PROFILE_EDIT_PROFILE']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! That was the problem! :)